# www e sem www para uma pasta e qualquer outro subdomínio para outra pasta

Tags: nginx

Eu tenho um domínio configurado no nginx da seguinte forma:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name   .dominio.com.br ~^(www\.)?(?<domain>.+)$;
    root /home/dominio.com.br/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Isso faz com que qualquer um destes links funcione:

dominio.com.br
subdominio.dominio.com.br

Caso eu configure um DNS de um outro domínio apontando para o IP deste meu servidor o app também funcione por causa dessa linha:

```
server_name   .dominio.com.br ~^(www\.)?(?<domain>.+)$;
```

Eu gostaria de poder direcionar para uma outra pasta caso o link for:

www.dominio.com.br
dominio.com.br

Ou seja, qualquer subdomínio (menos www) deve ir para uma pasta ja o subdomínio www e sem www ir para uma outra pasta.

Já tentei criando um novo bloco server {} como no exemplo abaixo, mas não funcionou:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name   dominio.com.br www.dominio.com.br;
    root /home/outra_pasta/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Como posso resolver esta questão?

Comment: Qual bloco tá sendo carregado primeiro?
Eles estão dentro do mesmo arquivo?
Se estiverem em arquivo diferentes, como é o nome dos arquivos na pasta sites-enabled?
Com o outro bloco não funcionou porque o nginx não reiniciou ou pq o o bloco não captou a requisição?